# How to replace NA's with specific data?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df1:

```
ID  Number
3   9
4   10
2   3
1   NA
8   5
6   4
9   NA
```

I would like to change the NAs to 1's, like below.

```
ID  Number
3   9
4   10
2   3
1   1
8   5
6   4
9   1
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R

```
df$Number[is.na(df$Number)] <- 1
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    mutate(Number = ifelse(is.na(Number), 1, Number))
```

Or with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setnafill(df, cols="Number", fill=1)
```

**Output**

```
  ID Number
1  3      9
2  4     10
3  2      3
4  1      1
5  8      5
6  6      4
7  9      1
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 9L), Number = c(9L, 
10L, 3L, NA, 5L, 4L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```